# Is it possible to use flask render_template to a php script

Tags: php, python, flask

I have a python flask application, but I have some old php scripts that I would want to reuse.

I am trying to parse some data from my flask application. When accessing it,  company login password is needed, so "curl" in php wouldn't really work. So I am thinking of parsing the data to the php scripts through `render_template`.

Is it possible to do something like this :

```
data= <some data>  
@app.route('/test')
def test():
   return render_template('my_php_scripts.php',input_data=data)
```

While in my php script, I do:

```
<?php
   $DataString=**{{input_data}}**
?>
```

If not, what would be a good way to do it?

Comment: I kind of love what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Researched a bit on my own, It doesn't seem to be possible. Since using flask render_template, it wouldn't be using the php interpreter. So how do people translate old php scripts into python environment? Do they simply rewrite everything? Or is there a way to easily convert them?

Answer (score 2):

So if you want process the php in python, you'll need to do something like

```
data = "Charles"
from subprocess import call
call(["php", "my_php_scripts.php", data])
```

where your php script looks something like

```
<?php
$DataString = $argv[1];
echo "Eat nachoes, $DataString!\r\n";
```

presuming the data is something fairly simple, or maybe you can convert it into a JSON if it's a more complex object and transfer it in that way.